# Inverse of $f(x,y)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(x)\tan^{-1}(y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Inverse of $f(x,y)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(x)\tan^{-1}(y)$. Finding the inverse of function with one variable is simple enough, but how can I find the inverse of this?

Comment: You have a function which transforms two reals into only one $z=f(x,y)$. Can you explain what the inverse would look like in your mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Both $\sin x$ and $\dfrac2\pi\cdot\arctan y$ take values on $(-1,1),$ so this boils down to finding two numbers when you know their product, which is absurd.

Comment: For instance, say $f(x,y)=\dfrac14.~$ Then both $x=\dfrac\pi6$ and $y=1,~$ as well as $x=\dfrac\pi2$ and $y=\sqrt2-1$ are viable solutions.

Comment: Furthermore, if $(x,y)=(a,b)$ is a solution, then so are $(b,a),~(-a,-b)$ and $(-b,-a).$